# Is the term "Shannon filter" appropriate for a naive filter based on the Shannon information entropy of a data set?

Tags: terminology, information-theory

This relatively simple question collapses neatly into the title. I have large swaths of numerical and categorical data that contain unknown amounts of signal relative to weak data modeling principles. From these data sets, I'm attempting to extract usable signal -- that is, data that is well-ordered, correctly transformed and modelled, and usable for stochastic ensemble construction and analysis that occurs downstream.

In order to do this, I have decided to construct what I am calling a *Shannon Filter:* a simple, naive system that computes the [Shannon information entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28information_theory%29) of each piece of data with respect to its current model, ranks the data in descending order (relative to a logitnormal distribution), and performs filtering at some confidence level yet to be determined.

While this is not yet a methods question (I may turn to http://dsp.stackexchange.com or http://crypto.stackexchange.com for that answer, since both spaces contain direct analogs to my problem), it is currently one of correct terminology. The phrase ["Shannon Filter"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22shannon+filter%22) appears to be in loose current usage, yet I can find no sourcing to back this up.

Would use of this term be considered appropriate in the statistical domain?

---

*I ask here, because of all the StackExchange sites that delve into this class of problem (inclusive of math, dsp, crypto, cs-theory, SO, and english; yikes!), abstract statistics seems to be the most relevant domain that I wish to apply this term within. I expect my system to be defined in the context of stochastic sampling and pairwise search algorithms digestible by statisticians, so I require a crisp, clear definition for this process that is technically correct.*